# Android: Inner class error

Tags: java, android, class, extends

I am developing an application in Android and have a problem. I have two classes A and B. Their code is as below(for example):

```
public class A extends View {
//declaration of constructors
...
    public class B extends Button {
    //declaration of constructors
    }
}
```

I try to add in xml the designer a 
class B, but I receive an error and it adds nothing.

```
<com.example.myproject.A.B
android:is="@+id/B1"
android:layout_wight="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
.../>
```

What is the probable error and how to make a class as shown above free of errors in the designer of xml ?

Comment: `$` instead `.` for inner class ... but it should be static class

Answer (score 1):

You can't use those classes as creating an instance of `B` would require a reference to `A` in the first place. You either make the `B` class `static` in `A` and use:

```
<view
   class="com.example.myproject.A$B"
   android:is="@+id/B1"
   android:layout_wight="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
/>
```

or you rethink your current class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
public class A extends View {
//declaration of constructors
...
    public static class B extends Button {
    //declaration of constructors
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
<view class="com.example.myproject.A$B"
    android:id="@+id/B1"
    android:layout_wight="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    .../>
```

The most important thing here is that `B` is `static` nested class, not just inner class. You can't instantiate an inner class if you don't have an instance of an outer class, which is `A` in your case.

Comment: Did you tried using `$` in the xml layout file like you recommend?

Comment: Oh, you're right, that's an error. Thank you for noticing it.